# Регистрация программы

Tags: регистрация, сертификат, юридические-аспекты

Подскажите, нужна ли регистрация программы, сертификат качества, регистрация авторских прав и т.д., для того что использовать программу в коммерческих целях?.. Или можно на основе доверительных отношений продавать ПО организациям и частным лицам? Кто нибудь занимался этим (выпускал на рынок свои программные продукты)? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ юриста ([Регистрация ПО](http://ilex.copiny.com/question/details/id/11347)):

Безусловно, в случае если Вы будете использовать ПО в коммерческих целях, регистрация необходима. Регистрация ПО - это удостоверение существования программы в объективной форме и указание на авторство. Регистрация программы для ЭВМ осуществляется в соответствии в соответствии с положениями Гражданского кодекса РФ по желанию правообладателя.

Answer (score 1):

А Вы когда-нибудь видели сертификаты качества для программ Microsoft, Oracle и т.д.? Сертификаты качества выдают ЭТИ фирмы только за дорого стоящее их имя, к которому, можно сказать, проникся уважением мир. Вот и по желанию программисты сертифицируются у этих фирм. Возможно, у этих же фирм и есть какие-то сертификаты качества для программ. Так, чтобы была сертификация у государства?!!! Это уже, по-моему, нонсенс. Тогда государство должно создавать комиссию, состоящую из профессиональных разработчиков или тестировщиков ПО, которые и выносили бы вердикт программе. Но это же бессмыслица, по-моему, для государств. Как я знаю работу некоторых частников в Беларуси, так они заключают договор о создании и сопровождении некоторого ПО, разрабатывают, получают деньги за программу и сопровождают свою программу. И никакого сертификата по своей программе не получают. Т.е. Тут уже в любом случае сертифицирующей стороной выступает заказчик. А как может знать какой-то эксперт, что же надо стороне-заказчику? 
Вы можете 100% создать патент на свою программу или кусок программного кода. Такие операции уже существуют и используются. Там есть много своих тонкостей, которые Вы должны уже узнавать именно в комиссии по сертификации.

Comment: И еще. В любом случае есть возможность зарегистрировать продукт интеллектуальной или другой деятельности на уровне государства, чтобы можно было, если что, требовать иски и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос был про использование программы в коммерческих целях...